# Не работает linear-gradient

Tags: css

Подскажите, в чём проблема кода ниже:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,.19), rgba(0,0,0,0));
```

По идее, стиль должен работать, но почему то в браузере ошибка. Подскажите как поправить.

**UPD.** Проверял и в опере и в хроме (последние версии)

**UPD.** Всё решилось само собой после перезагрузки!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, Ваш браузер не поддерживает данное свойство.

Многие браузеры не поддерживают функцию `linear-gradient`, но в то же время поддерживают такие же функции, только под другим названием, например `Firefox3.6+` поддерживает `-moz-linear-gradient`, `Chrome` и `Safari4+` поддерживают `-webkit-gradient`, `Opera11.10+` поддерживает `-o-linear-gradient` и т.д.

Вместо того, что-бы прописывать всё это вручную, советую пользоватся градиент-генераторами, такими, как [этот](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: Пользуюсь генератором и хаками тоже, не помогает!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так код градиента точно срабатывает.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba($black, .8) 0%,
        rgba($black, 0) 50%,
        rgba($black, .8) 100%);
```